# Activity crashes (File handling and camera)

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

Following activity takes a picture, stores it in storage and displays it in the ImageView of the Activity. When I click a photo and hit okay button, a message 'Unfortunately, Camera has stopped' appears and Camera activity screen is displayed. ImageView is not set. Images clicked are stored in the storage (Checked with File explorer)

Camera.java

```
public class Camera extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
String mCurrentPhotoPath;
ImageView ivCaptured;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    ivCaptured = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCaptured);
    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Camera.this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
        //galleryAddPic();
        setPic();
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

/*private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}*/

private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = ivCaptured.getLayoutParams().width;
    int targetH = ivCaptured.getLayoutParams().height;

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outWidth;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    ivCaptured.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
}
```

activity_camera.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/ivCaptured"
    android:src="@drawable/photo"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan">

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Home" />
    <activity android:name=".Camera" />
    <activity android:name=".History"></activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:readPermission="com.company.app.fileprovider.READ">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>

</application>

</manifest>
```

file_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

LogCat:

```
09-01 18:23:38.278 11159-11159/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-01 18:23:38.378 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan I/ActivityThread: Pub com.example.android.fileprovider: android.support.v4.content.FileProvider
09-01 18:23:38.438 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
09-01 18:23:38.442 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
09-01 18:23:38.442 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14517: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
09-01 18:23:38.442 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
09-01 18:23:38.442 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
09-01 18:23:38.442 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14521: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
09-01 18:23:38.442 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
09-01 18:23:38.494 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
09-01 18:23:38.494 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14417: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
09-01 18:23:38.506 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
09-01 18:23:38.518 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
09-01 18:23:38.518 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 407: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
09-01 18:23:38.518 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-01 18:23:38.522 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
09-01 18:23:38.522 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 429: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
09-01 18:23:38.522 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-01 18:23:38.778 11159-11163/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 207K, 3% free 10939K/11271K, paused 151ms+1ms, total 214ms
09-01 18:23:38.814 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
09-01 18:23:38.830 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
09-01 18:23:38.834 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
09-01 18:23:38.866 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-01 18:23:38.874 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
09-01 18:23:38.962 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb9615438): name, size, mSize = 2, 4096, 4096
09-01 18:23:40.690 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-01 18:23:41.906 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 47K, 3% free 11140K/11399K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
09-01 18:23:41.914 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::flush: target size: 2457
09-01 18:23:41.914 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 2, 4096, 0
09-01 18:23:46.990 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-01 18:23:46.994 11159-11159/com.kjsce.beproject.samarthan D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb9615438): name, size, mSize = 6, 4096, 4096
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace from your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Your information from LogCat does not show [the Java stack trace associated with your crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this), and so it will not help you or us.

Other problems include:

- You are setting `mCurrentPhotoPath` to `"file:" + image.getAbsolutePath()`, and that value is neither a filesystem path nor a `Uri`.
- You are calling `setPic()` in cases where you are not taking a picture (if `photoFile` is `null`).
- You are calling `setPic()` before the user takes a picture, as `startActivityForResult()` is asynchronous. Move your `setPic()` call into `onActivityResult()`, and then only if you get `RESULT_OK` (indicating that hopefully the user took a picture).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you checking if a camera exists. Ditto on Commonsware, your log is not the crash. Following you seem to be following the official doc. Make sure your code is exactly like theres, plus this check below.

[Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
}
```

I personally use

```
int numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
if (numCameras > 0) {
  hasCamera = true;
}
```

That said on some devices you will still crash (looking at you Asus nexus) if you try to access the rear camera explicitly, but that is outside the scope of this answer.

I mention all this as I see you are on an emulator which is very problematic for accessing sudo hardware.